# uninstall homebrew without uninstalling packages

Tags: terminal, install, homebrew, macos

I want to show someone how to install homebrew.

I want to uninstall homebrew (so that I no longer have a `brew` command) and then paste the install command into my terminal, and it goes through a normal installation procedure.

But once it's done installing, I should still have all of the packages I've already installed.

Comment: Unclear: is this really just for show? Do you want a production machine use for this demo? Isn't `rm /usr/local/bin/brew` enough?

Comment: @LangLangC this is really just for show. idk if that's enough, I'm assuming the brew install script will behave differently if homebrew is already installed